# Difference between evaluation of while(n>0) and while(n!=0)

Tags: algorithm, loops, while-loop

Is the evaluation of `while(n>0)` and `while(n!=0)` different? Basically both are to exit in the same condition. So is there a scenario when one of them should be used? Or will it make a difference in the performance efficiency by changing the loop condition when the number of times the loop being evaluated being the same?

Comment: It matters depending on the starting value of `n` - if it starts with a negative (or overflowed) value they behave quite differently. Also, I think there might be a tiny performance impact where one assembly instruction differs, but that's really pointless micro-optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your platform, but in general, it will perform identically.
For example, for x86 architecture `cmp` operator will be used for both `>` or `!=`. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow) you can read more.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that the condition is not the same, there is no difference performance wise.

Comment: ...and where is your proof that there is no perfomance difference?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Thats based on the fact that machine instructions for conditional jumps in typical CPUs don't differ in runtime. But you are welcome to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Henry: there could be a difference in behavior if the branch prediction logics of both types of tests differ. (Though I don't really believe they do.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the difference will be neutral.

Anyway, one could maliciously think of special schemes like

```
while (n > 0)
{
  ...
  n++;
}
```

vs.

```
while (n != 0)
{
  ...
  n++;
}
```

where the compiler can infer that in the first snippet the test needs to be done on the first iteration only, and unroll the `while` into an `if`.

Comment: i am sorry really did not understand your point about unrolling while into if in the first case.

Comment: `if (n > 0) { ...; n++; while (true) { ...; n++; } }`

Comment: Ok i thot of the scenario where n was decremented :). So if the code is rewritten in this form there would be a performance change?

Comment: @Vini: in any case, nothing measureable.